# In Visual Studio data UI customization , my custom usercontrol gives error does not allow drag/drop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In my project I am using a custom usercontrol that inherits from devexpress gridcontrol. Altough the gridcontrol works well with **Visual Studio Data UI Customization** my user control gives a warning , do not allow drag the data on UI.

Is there any Visual studio logs to display the reason of warning/error ?  Or does anyone suggest any basic tests to detect the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution .

I had  updated the namespace of  the usercontrol yesterday. But today as see to copy of this usercontrol one in old namespace, one in current namespace.  So Visual Studio has a bug , when you change a usercontrols namespace it will not automatically update the control in Visual Studio Data UI Customization .

So if you are using any usercontrol in your project and assign it any Visual Studio Data UI Customization components keep in mind to update that field manually.

Anyway Visual Studio Data UI Customization is a good way of coding.